# 'objType' is not defined... Actually, it is, so why is this happening?

Tags: vb.net, types, undefined, directcast

As you seen in this picture below, for some reason my DirectCast wont except ANYTHING for the second argument.  It says it requires a type, but, it won't take any object at all!

[image]

Thanks for any help!  I'm using VB.net so all .net answers are acceptable :)

**EDIT**

Ok, so apparently I'm not giving it the right kind of `type`.  Could somebody please clarify this?  Assuming the type it needs to cast to is `gridElement`, what should I replace objType with?

Comment: 'It says it requires a type, but, it won't take any object at all'; perhaps because it requires _a type_? DbType, is a good example of a type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DirectCast` requires an object prototype (i.e. just giving it the intended class name) rather than a `System.Type` descriptor object. To cast an object using a `System.Type`, you will want to utilize [CTypeDynamic()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee835926%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
Return CTypeDynamic(createElementByIdAndLayer.MemberwiseClone(), objType)
```

The error is essentially telling you a class with the type name "objType" does not exist.

Comment: VS isn't recognizing CTypeDynamic, do I need to reference something?

Comment: `CTypeDynamic` is part of the .NET 4.0 Framework. I assume you aren't targeting that particular library.

Comment: Hmm... sadly not.  I was trying to target the most commonly installed framework.  I've got it downgraded all the way to 2.0 I believe...  Sorry.  +1 anyways.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can safely target 3.5 these days. It ships standard with Server 2008 and Windows 7 and is flagged critical update for XP. Unfortunately that won't help this situation anyway. Does your return type conform to an interface?

Comment: It returns a class `gridElement` that inherits from a class called `luaPlugin` that I made.  I don't have a current understanding of interfaces, I should probably go read about them...  So no, I don't believe that it conforms to an interface.  I'll update my project to 3.5 as well...

Comment: If you know ahead of time that you always WANT a gridElement and the object can be cast to a gridElement, you can call Return DirectCast(createElementByIdAndLayer.MemberwiseClone(), gridElement)

Answer (score 2):

Its expecting a "Type", not a "Type Object".

What is the return value of the function?