# How to recast objects from a Dictionary(Of String, Object) in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, casting, npoi

I have a program that runs a bunch of different types of tests. The each test has a bunch of different settings that can be set. I am trying to export the settings that were used for each test to an excel file. Write now I have all the settings stored in a Dictionary(Of String, Object) because the value of the settings can be different types i.e (Double, Integer, String, Boolean). I am trying to recast the values from the dictionary like so but the DirectCast does not like the t, It says type t is not defined. I also tried CType but it does not seem to work. settings is of type Dictionary(Of String, Object)

```
Private Sub writeTestSettings(ByRef book As HSSFWorkbook, ByVal settings As Dictionary(Of String, Object))
    Dim settingsSheet As HSSFSheet = book.CreateSheet("Test Configuration")

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each key In settings.Keys
        Dim row = settingsSheet.CreateRow(i)
        Dim cell1 As HSSFCell = row.CreateCell(0)
        cell1.SetCellValue(key)
        Dim cell2 As HSSFCell = row.CreateCell(1)
        Dim value As Object = settings(key)
        Dim t As Type = value.GetType()
        cell2.SetCellValue(DirectCast(value, t))

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to indicate what the error is that you're getting.  "It doesn't like it" isn't very clear.

Comment: Yes I apologize. I updated the post. The error says Type 't' is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on .NET 4.0 or later, you can use [CTypeDynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee835926%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) instead. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534718/objtype-is-not-defined-actually-it-is-so-why-is-this-happening).

```
    Dim t As Type = value.GetType()
    cell2.SetCellValue(CTypeDynamic(value, t))
```

You might also want to consider changing your settings' storage mechanism a bit. Putting several different types in a Dictionary of Objects may make future maintenance and debugging obnoxious. As an off the cuff idea, one possibility would be a simple wrapper class with private type-specific dictionaries and overloaded accessors and mutators.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast directly because you don't know the type at compile time. It's not very clean code but you could do it with a Select Case:

```
Select Case t
    Case GetType(Double)
        Dim doubleValue = CType(value, Double)
        cell2.SetCellValue(doubleValue)
    Case GetType(Integer)
        Dim integerValue = CType(value, Integer)
        cell2.SetCellValue(integerValue)
    ...
End Select
```